# How to get a matrix of mean differences between groups in R

Tags: r, statistics

I'm doing a bunch of T-tests using the pairwise.t.test function in R, which creates a snazzy matrix of P values for all the comparisons like

```
date    p.value.2016.04.18  p.value.2016.04.20  p.value.2016.04.22
2016-04-20  1.00E+00    NA  NA
2016-04-22  1.00E+00    1.22E-01    NA
2016-04-24  1.00E+00    1.00E+00    1.00E+00
2016-04-26  1.00E+00    5.01E-01    1.00E+00
2016-04-28  1.28E-02    1.03E-01    6.20E-06
```

I'd like to make a matching matrix of differences between the means of the groups. My google-fu has failed me. Can you help a humble stats monkey out, SO?

Comment: like this https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help//2012-November/340452.html ?

Comment: That's pretty close. Maybe I can make it work. I need to separate my data by group. The current format is like:
group1 value1
group1 value2
group2 value1
group2 value 2

etc

Comment: I had to do an intermediate step to get the means by group, then I could do the outer to get what I needed. The only question left is: is there a way to get the names for each group to be the colname and rowname?

Comment: There might be some better way to do it, but if nothing else you can write the results to an object then use `colnames` and `rownames`.

Comment: @Hack-R put your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example from this [famous listserv](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help//2012-November/340452.html):

```
Table1 <- matrix(10:6, ncol = 1)
rownames(Table1) <- letters[1:5]
Table1

t(outer(Table1[,1], Table1[,1], `-`))
```